# isometrygroup of hypercube

Tags: group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry, isometry

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show, that an isometry $\alpha \in Isom([-1,1]^n)$ is already determined by it's action on the vertices. I really just want to use the invariance of distance. I don't want to use the fact, that $\alpha$ has to be linear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be the vertex set. The map $(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$ where $d$
is the Euclidean distance is maximized for $x$ and $y$ in the cube when $x$
and $y$ are opposite vertices. So any isometry fixes the vertex set.
Now it is reasonably straightforward that an isometry restricts to a Euclidean transformation
on the vertex set. Finally each point in the cube is
determined by the distances to the vertices, so the isometry must be a
Euclidean transformation on the whole cube.

Comment: The question ja, WHY each point is determined by the vertices

Comment: @dish just look at the distances to the vertices...